# How to delete many messages at once

Tags: ios, quickblox

I want to delete quickblox chat messages

After reading the documentation, I saw that I can delete 1 message at a time

```
[QBChat deleteMessageWithID:@"53a04938e4b0afa821474844" delegate:self];
```

Is there a way to delete many messages of one of the participants in the chat, without deleting the other user's chat ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do it

Will add this feature in the nearest release